# How do you change the height value when more items are added to highcharts dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have the following problem - if i increase the amount of items in highcharts piechart the legend items get cut off as the height is a set amount - how can i change the height if more items are added - here is the current example: http://jsfiddle.net/zidski/34fUV/10/

Comment: Pie charts aren't so great for comprehending the data when you start playing with more than 2 values. Some in the data viz community would argue the end user is better served if you employ a bar chart or column chart in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
//amusing data array contains number of legends, I know it's nested inside something else

var height = //get containers original height

var new_height = height + (data.length * 10);

$("#highcharts-0").css("{height:"+new_height+"}");
```